# The server at www.localhost.com is taking too long to respond

Tags: php, apache

A very strange thing is happening. I am running a script on a new server (it works on my current server and laptop).

The strange thing is that I only get it to (sort of) work when I increase memory limit to 1024M (!). It is extracting a large zip file and going through the files, so I thought it was normal. Instead of this script terminating or ending with errors. I get an error from my browser:

> The server at www.localhost.com is
>   taking too long to respond.

Localhost.com? The web server is just `localhost:9090` and I can see Apache is still running. Maybe Apache crashes momentarily and it can't find the server? But nothing about apache crashing in the log files.

This isn't a server issue, its more to do with my PHP script and memory usage I think, so no need to move to server fault.

What could be the problem? How can I narrow do the cause, I am at loss here!

The server is a windows server running Apache 2.2 with PHP version 5.3.2. May laptop and the  other working server are running version 5.3.0 and 5.3.1 for PHP.

Thanks all for any help

Comment: It's probably Firefox's "intelligent address lookup" feature. Can you try the same using IE?

Comment: Just tried it on IE6 and it gives me "The page cannot be displayed". Not much else. :(

Comment: If your script causes an infinite loop, or eats up memory, you may try restarting apache and see if that fixes the issue. I have had this happen a few times when a script I wrote ate up all the memory and or infinite looped. Restarting generally helps. And if it does help, well look at your script and try to make it a bit more efficient.

Comment: how come its www.localhost.com? is it not just http://localhost:9090 ? u changed hosts file?

Comment: are you typing into your browswer <pre>http://localhost:9090/your_page_name.php</pre>? You might also try <pre>http://127.0.0.1:9090/your_page_name.php</pre>

Comment: Shoban: FF has a lookup type deal, where if you type in  bob it will look for bob.com www.bob.com  etc till it finds a match (if it finds one see Pekka's response).

Comment: @Shoban - Host file has only one entry and that is localhost, no .com. @Victacu - yes I am. @Premiso - I have restarted a lot of times already and its the same.

Comment: so how will it work if u use .com .???

Comment: @Shoban - I don't think you have understood my problem. The actual problem is my browser redirecting to www.localhost.com which is not the URI of my local web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that,

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024MB' );
```

I'd pop this in the top of the script and see what comes out. It should show you errors and the like.

The other thing, have you checked `fopen` and the path of the file which it's loading?

> **Abs** said,
>
> check files being zipped up can be zipped by PHP (permissions
> especially on a Windows OS with multi
> users)

Comment: Interesting, I placed the above at the top of my script and came back with a blank page straight away?! There should be quotes for '`1024mb'`. Just checking all file paths for the hundredth time!

Comment: All file paths are correct as well. It doesn't even show an error!

Comment: Oops, sorry. How very odd. Have you tried backing up your apache httpd.conf and replacing it with a vanilla one and then trying? Just to eliminate the server as a problem? Are you sure `9090` is a free port?

Comment: yes 9090 is a free port. I have found the problem now though, the files I was trying zip up with my PHP script had an access file that was open and for some reason it was being denied to zip that up. I thought php_zip only tried to zip things up in read only mode and this was probably being refused. So I removed that file by closing the  Access database being used by another user and it worked!

Comment: can you edit your question to include what I said above i.e. check files being zipped up can be zipped by PHP (permissions especially on a Windows OS with multi users) and I will close this question using your answer. This is a weird case that others need to know about to eliminate frustration.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this problem too, and none of these sites really helped until I started looking at the same thing for people using Internet Explorer. The way I fixed it is to open up the system hosts file, located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and then uncomment out the line that mentions `::1`, which is needed for IPv6. After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your system's munged up and isn't treating `localhost` as the local `127.0.0.1` address. Is your `hosts` file properly configured? This is most likely why you're getting the "too long to respond" error:

```
marc@panic:~$ host www.localhost.com
www.localhost.com has address 64.99.64.32

marc@panic:~$ wget www.localhost.com
--2010-08-03 22:41:05--  http://www.localhost.com/
Resolving www.localhost.com... 64.99.64.32
Connecting to www.localhost.com|64.99.64.32|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

`www.localhost.com` is full valid hostname as far as the DNS system is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a php guru by any means but are you writing the extracted files to a temporary local storage location that is within the scope of the application?  Because if you are not then I think what is happening is that the application is storing the zip file and extracted files in memory and then is attempting to read them.  So if it is a large zip and/or the extracted files are large that would introduce a huge amount of overhead on top of the overhead introduced by your read and processing actions.

So if you are not already I would extracted the files and write them to disk in their own folder, dispose of the zip file at this point, and then iterate over the files in your newly created directory and perform whatever actions you need to on them.